# Can the inertia factor of a black hole be used to infer its density profile?

Tags: black-holes, density, singularities, inertia

The Sun's inertia factor of ~0.07 suggests a stark contrast between the density of its outer shells (very low density) and its core (very dense). The same applies to the rest of the solar system. Earth's inertia factor of ~0.33 suggests a core and a mantle that are not vastly different in density (relatively). Our moon's inertia factor of ~0.39 suggests that its density profile is nearly uniform.

I am stepping way outside of my scope here, but I can not believe that there are singularities at the centers of black holes, and I am under the impression that this is one reason why GR is believed to be incomplete, correct?

**My question is the following:** Can we measure the inertia factors of black holes? And if so, wouldn't this be helpful to suggest that the interiors of black holes are or aren't singularities?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the existence of the singularity in GR is one of the primary (but not the only) causes of concern. I'm not fully sure of what you mean by the inertia factor, but I assume it to be something that contains the information of matter distribution.

In classical GR, however, black holes are considered [vacuum solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_solution_(general_relativity)#:%7E:text=In%20general%20relativity%2C%20a%20vacuum,non%2Dgravitational%20fields%20are%20present.) to Einstein equations. This means that apart from the curvature singularity, no matter is contained behind the horizon.

You can say that real black holes should be quantum mechanical in nature and, therefore, might have a substructure. But I'm not aware of how one can measure that yet. One way to study the nature of near-horizon physics is via the observations of the [photon sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_sphere) made by the event horizon telescope. But so far, we have not found any conclusive deviations from the predictions of GR.